# Finding DropDownList index by text

Tags: asp.net

I have a populated DropDownList. How do I find the index whose Text value is "x"?

Comment: on client side or on server side?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you want to get value on server side you can follow this.

```
ddlsample.SelectedIndex = ddlsample.Items.IndexOf(ddlsample.Items.FindByValue("x")); // If you want to find text by value field.
ddlsample.SelectedIndex = ddlsample.Items.IndexOf(ddlsample.Items.FindByText("x"));// If you want to find text by TextField.
```

Answer (score 0):

try tis.

ddlsample2.SelectedIndex = ddlsample.FindStringExact(ddlsample.Text);