# How can I use DataTextField on an element that is not a ListControl?

Tags: asp.net, sql, drop-down-menu, datasource

So here's my situation: I have a DropDownList that I populate when a certain event is triggered. To populate it, I execute a SQL query that returns two columns: ID and Name. I bind the Name to the DropDownList using DataSource/DataTextField/DataValueField, but I want to save the ID as well (to use in a second query). How can I do this?

I have tried saving the ID to a hidden input field, because I want to use it but not display it to the user. But input is not a ListControl, so it doesn't work. How do I get the matching ID of the Name selected in the DropDownList?

```
    string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id, Name FROM Users WHERE Age > 10";

    DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    con.Open();
    dAdapter.Fill(objDs);
    con.Close();
    if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        NameDropDown.DataSource = objDs.Tables[0];
        NameDropDown.DataTextField = "Name";
        NameDropDown.DataValueField = "Name";
        NameDropDown.DataBind();
        NameDropDown.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
    }
    else
    {
        NameDropDown.Items.Clear();
        NameDropDown.Items.Insert(0, "No names found");
    }
```

Comment: Why not change the datavaluefield to be bound to ID and the textfield to be bound to name?  Generally the VALUES are what you store in the DB, the names are what people recognize.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Dunno *why* I didn't think of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    NameDropDown.DataSource = objDs.Tables[0];
    NameDropDown.DataTextField = "Name";
    NameDropDown.DataValueField = "ID"; /*why wouldn't this be ID*/
    NameDropDown.DataBind();
    NameDropDown.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
```

Comment: ok, assuming I take this approach, how do I recover the name? Right now, to get name and ID, I'm using:         string ID = NameDropDown.SelectedValue.ToString(); 
        int NameIndex = NameDropDown.SelectedIndex;
        string NameFromDropDown = NameDropDown.Items[NameIndex].ToString();

Comment: is there an easier way to get the name, than getting the selectedindex and using Items[SelectedIndex]?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014864/finding-dropdownlist-index-by-text may help