# How to prevent duplication in DropDownlist in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web form when i click on search button DropDownList must select the text among the Dataitems available in dropdownlist but problem with my code is that it insert the duplicate Dataitem text instead of selecting original Dataitem. Following is my code

```
sqlChk = s.callingSP("SP_SearchCase", txtOfficeSerialNO.Text.Trim());
    if (sqlChk.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        divEmpMast.Style.Add("display", "block");

        lblMsg.Visible = false;

        txtSNO.Text = sqlChk.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SNo"].ToString();

        txtSending.Text = sqlChk.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DateOfSending"].ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlChk.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FrmWhere"].ToString()))
        {
            // Write your Custom Code
            sqlChk.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FrmWhere"] = "None";
        }
        else
           ddlSubdistrict.SelectedItem.Text=sqlChk.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FrmWhere"].ToString();
```

Please help

Comment: I don't see any relation to your description and code.

Comment: you `dropdown` has a list and you want to select the item dynamically according to data?

Comment: @Bharadwaj actually problem with this line ddlSubdistrict.SelectedItem.Text=sqlChk.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FrmWhere"].ToString(); it is assigning additional value instead of selecting existing values.

Comment: @ankitsrist Answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014864/finding-dropdownlist-index-by-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ddlSubdistrict.SelectedValue=sqlChk.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FrmWhere"].ToString();
```

Or you can also try

```
DDL.SelectedIndex = DDL.Items.IndexOf(DDL.Items.FindByText(sqlChk.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FrmWhere"].ToString()));

Or

DDL.SelectedIndex = DDL.Items.IndexOf(DDL.Items.FindByValue(sqlChk.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FrmWhere"].ToString()));
```

Comment: I am getting this error 'ddlSubdistrict' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value....

Comment: public void fillName()
    {
        s.fillCombo(txtWhomToSend, "select distinct Name from tbl_Add_Member order by Name asc", "Name", "Name");
        //txtWhomToSend.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("None", "0"));
    }

Comment: I think your dropdown does not contain name which was returned by your search query.

Comment: Thanks your "you can also try" code works...but there is another problem arose None option of dropdown has been removed ?

Comment: @ankitsrist `None option of dropdown has been removed` what do you mean ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ddlSubdistrict.Items.FindByValue(sqlChk.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FrmWhere"].ToString()).Selected = true
```